# CanvasDrawingSession 9-patch support?

Tags: uwp, win2d

Does [CanvasDrawingSession](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession.htm) have built-in 9-patch support? Or do I have to piece it together from their other DrawImage methods?

Comment: What do you mean the "9-patch support"? Do you mean support [Nine-patch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) used in Android? If so, I'm afraid there is no built-in support.

Comment: not Android specifically; but that kind of drawing, yes. iOS does it too, with https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624127-resizableimagewithcapinsets

Comment: For different platforms, there are different "9-patch" supports. For example, in Android, it uses special `.9.png` file, but in UWP, it uses [Image.NineGrid property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242756). The 9-patch support is not set by `CanvasDrawingSession`.